# Fraction of vegetation calculation for the whole Landsat Image Collection with Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8

I'm trying to calculate Land Surface Temperature for my image Collection of 294 Landsat 8 images. I've calculated NDVI and try to apply the solution given in the previous question: [Calculating LST from Landsat 8 in Google Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314374/calculating-lst-from-landsat-8-in-google-earth-engine).
In this solution, it is given for one Landsat Image, but I need to do it for the whole image collection. I try to write the fraction of vegetation as a function, but it gave an error :

> FV: Layer error: ImageCollection.mosaic: Error in
>   map(ID=LC08_173034_20161212): Number.subtract: Parameter 'left' is
>   required.

My code is:

```
//Adding Stations:
Map.addLayer(stations,{},'stations');
Map.centerObject(stations);

// Function to cloud mask Landsat 8.
var maskL8 = function(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(3).int();
  var cloudsBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(5).int();
  var snowBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(4).int();
  // Get the QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0).and(
            qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0)).and(
            qa.bitwiseAnd(snowBitMask).eq(0));
  return image
      .addBands(image.select(['B10'], ['thermal']).multiply(0.1))
      .updateMask(mask);
};

//Finding and filtering Landsat8 data:
var L8_filtered = Landsat8.filterDate('2016-09-01', '2017-08-30')
  .filterBounds(stations)
  .map(maskL8);
  //.select(L8_bands,bands);
var rgb_L8= {min:0, max:4000, bands:['B4','B3','B2']};
Map.addLayer(L8_filtered, rgb_L8, 'RGB_L8');

var vis_thermal = {min:270, max:400, bands:['thermal']};
Map.addLayer(L8_filtered, vis_thermal, 'thermal');

print('Size of Landsat8 Filtered Collection', L8_filtered.size());//294
print(L8_filtered, 'collection');

//NDVI Function:
function addNDVI(image){
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']);
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
}

var L8_wNDVI = L8_filtered.map(addNDVI);
Map.addLayer(L8_wNDVI, {bands: 'nd', min : 0, max : 1}, 'NDVI');

//Fractional Vegetation Function
function calc_fv(image){
  var ndvi = image.select(['nd']);
  var min = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
     reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
     geometry: stations,
     scale: 30,
     maxPixels: 1e9
     }).values().get(0));
  var max = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
      geometry: stations,
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1e9
     }).values().get(0));
  var fv = image.expression(ndvi.subtract(min).divide(max.subtract(min)));
  return image.addBands(fv);
}

var L8_fv = L8_wNDVI.map(calc_fv);
Map.addLayer(L8_fv, {bands: 'FV', min : 0, max : 1}, 'FV');
```

How can I revise my code?

Comment: Th problem is probably coming from an image having only masked pixels within the reigon 'stations'. So you can probably filter those images first. Giving access and a link to the geometry 'stations' enables someone to help you further.

Comment: @Kuik when I exclude the geometry: stations line I still get an error message of 'FV: Layer error: ImageCollection.mosaic: Error in map(ID=LC08_173034_20160923):
String: Unable to convert object to string.' here is the lınk to my code https://code.earthengine.google.com/35e35933ff664d76ce7d550489553988

Comment: @Ayda 'Collection.loadTable: Permission denied for Fusion Table'